# onPress() is not working with react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

onPress() is not working for me. I'm using react navigation. I'm using createStackNavigator() with createBottomTabNavigator(). The onPress() is working in the home tab, but not working in other tab...
In home tab when i click a button it goes to other tab `props.navigation.navigate("Expenses")`. onPress in the home tab is working but not working in other tab.

Other tab

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableNativeFeedback } from "react-native"

class Expenses extends Component {
  state = {
    showing: false
  }
  handleClick = () => console.log("object")

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedback
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() => {
          this.handleClick()
        }}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Hello world</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    )
  }
}
Expenses.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: "Expense",
  headerTintColor: "#fff",
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#EE3E54"
  }
}
```

mainTabNavigation

```
import React from "react"
import { Platform, View } from "react-native"
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator
} from "react-navigation"

import TabBarIcon from "../components/TabBarIcon"
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen"
import LinksScreen from "../screens/LinksScreen"
import SettingsScreen from "../screens/SettingsScreen"
import ExpensesScreen from "../screens/Expenses"

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: "screen" },
  default: {}
})
//HeaderLeft Layout
const HeaderRight = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 16 }}>
      <TabBarIcon
        name="ios-paper-plane"
        onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: "Plan",
        headerRight: <HeaderRight />,
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#EE3E54"
        }
      }
    },
    Expenses: ExpensesScreen
  },
  config
)

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: "Trans.",
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "#EE3E54"
  },

  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === "ios"
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`
          : "ios-analytics"
      }
    />
  )
}

HomeStack.path = ""

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Links: LinksScreen
  },
  config
)

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: "Calendar",
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "#EE3E54"
  },
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-link" : "md-calendar"}
    />
  )
}

LinksStack.path = ""

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Settings: SettingsScreen
  },
  config
)

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: "More",
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "#EE3E54"
  },
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-options" : "ios-more"}
    />
  )
}

SettingsStack.path = ""

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
    LinksStack,
    SettingsStack
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
)

tabNavigator.path = ""

export default tabNavigator
```

onPress is not woking in other tab, but working in home tab..

Comment: Why do you put OnPress in VIew?

Comment: Sorry i thought , onPress can be use with <View>..